# I am using vuetify and I have a v-text-field and it should only accept numbers. How can I validate this using the regex?

Tags: regex, vue.js, vuetify.js

Validating the input number using regex

```
<v-text-field v-model="number" :rules="input" prepend-icon="info" label="5 digit number" required></v-text-field>



input: [v => !!v || 'This field is required',
v=>/\d/.test(v)||'This field only accept numbers],
```

User input: hello

Expected output: This field only accept numbers

Output I get: *accepts the string*

Comment: It says syntax error

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a quote in your code. Your regexp also checks for the presence of a single digit - what you're looking for is one or more digits from start to end.

```
rules: [v => !!v || 'This field is required',
        v => /^\d+$/.test(v)||'This field only accept numbers']
```

Comment: Thank you! must have overlooked that missing quote

Comment: I believe this logic fails when the number is 0, as it trips up on the "required" rule `!!v` logic.